# One Question but on multiple domains of SX

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, site-crossover

Most of the times it happens to me that I have a question that is partly related to one domain and partly to the other domain(s). Asking a question on one domain has the side of effect of losing the answers that could be provided by the active users of other domains and asking it multiple times on different times will be wasting of resources. As a result I would like to know if there is going to be any external part in the question submission form, regarding on which domains one wants his question to appear?

Comment: This is hard to answer without some specifics. Often questions can be broken down, and you'll have the best luck when questions are put in front of the best group of people to answer a question. It's OK to ask here on Meta "this is my question; where should I ask it?"